# Windows Linux compatibility layer. Function not implemented?

Tags: c, linux, windows, ubuntu, shared-memory

**ORIGINAL:**

I've been trying to implement a basic shared memory program using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (aka Bash on Ubuntu on Windows). Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define KEY 1374

int shmid;
char *dataPtr;

int main (void) {
    shmid = shmget((key_t)KEY,1024, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    dataPtr = shmat(shmid, (void*)0,0);
    if(dataPtr == (char*)(-1))
        perror("shmat error");
    strcpy(dataPtr,"test");
    sleep(10);
    shmdt(dataPtr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}
```

I compiled it with GCC without any error or warning, but when I tried to run it, I got this error message:

> shmat error: Function not implemented
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I tried to get to the bottom of this error, but when I googled it, I
[literally got nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYe04.jpg).

So the question is: did I horribly messed-up something very simple, or is it possible that the shared-memory system isn't implemented on "Ubuntu on Windows"?

**EDIT:**

I tried to run my code on my faculty's linux server, and it worked fine. So apparently the problem is with the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows system. The shared-memory system probably isn't implemented at all.

Comment: I doubt you messed up, BoUoW is experimental at the moment so it's likely that not all functionality is available.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yep, you were right.